# Case Activity Reporter vs Creator

Tags: civicase, activities, drupal-views

We have a backlog of activities that we hope to enter into our CiviCRM cases. We hired an individual to do data entry, but we want to distinguish between the "case reporter" (person who actually completed the activity) versus the creator of the activity (the individual who is entering the activities on behalf of the reporter). Currently, when creating an activity, the reporter is autogenerating the data entry person. If we change this user to be the person who actually completed the activity, is there a separate CiviCRM field that captures the creator on the backend?

I'm on Drupal 7. I'm trying to create a report in Views that will show the reporter and creator on a table.

Comment: Re 'data entry' - if you have the activities in a spreadsheet you can import them rather than creating them individually via the GUI.  Depends what your data is like and how many you have but might be worth scripting an import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use

Source contact as who is creating the activity

Assignee contact as actually completed the activity

Comment: Interesting. Looks like source contact is not actually the creator of the the activity. This is the "Reporter" field in case activities which can be changed. For example, I can create the activity and list you as the reporter. Views will read you as the source contact. But yes, I technically could use this workaround as the assignee is the person who completes the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Pradeep's answer should work. But there is actually an entry in civicrm_log where the modified_id is the true logged in user even if you change the Reported By field.

But I don't know if it's usable in Views.

You could also create a custom field for activities to store the logged-in user.